# Necessary time to let a particle at equilibrium point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I remember that there exists a demonstration showing that this time is actually infinite, but I cannot find it. We have a potential $V(x)$ that has a local max, and a local min at least.
If we give to a particle energy $E=V(x_{min})$ or $E=V(x_{max})$, what is the time it takes to move to $x_{min}/x_{max}$?

I know you can start from the integral of the energy.

$$t-t_{0}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}(E-V(x))}}$$

Does anybody know where can I find it?

Comment: You should be able to find out that yourself. Just try to convert it into a differential equation by seeing that the left hand side is dt. If you still need a hint, substitute dx/dt = v(velocity) and see where this leads to.

Comment: Which potential?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I remmember a V(x), with the only condition it had a local minimun and local maximun.